# Read txt file with hash tag (#) delimiter

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to read a lot of txt files that are hash tag delimited into R.

For example:

```
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
Dora#58529#26/04/2012#
```

When I try the following only the first column is loaded, probably because everything after the first hash tag is interpreted as a comment.

```
(df <- read.table("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64191100/hashtagdel.txt",sep="#"))
```

Output:

```
#     V1
# 1 Dora
# 2 Dora
# 3 Dora
# 4 Dora
# 5 Dora
# 6 Dora
# 7 Dora
# 8 Dora
# 9 Dora
```

I do not want to change the hash tag in every file by another character (I didn't create the files). Does somebody know a work-around?

Comment: Actually, this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789282/read-table-while-using-as-delimiter-does-not-work?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `?read.table`:

> `comment.char`
>   character: a character vector of length one containing a single character or an empty string. Use "" to turn off the interpretation of comments altogether.

So you want something like `read.table(*, sep="#", comment.char="")`

Answer (score 6):

Use `read.delim` instead...

```
df <- read.delim("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64191100/hashtagdel.txt" , header = FALSE , sep="#")
df
#   V1    V2         V3 V4
#1 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#2 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#3 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#4 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#5 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#6 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#7 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#8 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
#9 Dora 58529 26/04/2012 NA
```